# Memory Leak in WPF

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, 3d

I wrote a very simple newbie app with a 6-sided polyhedron (a "box") which rotates 180 degrees when I click a button. and then rotates back again on the next click.  Every rotation grabs another 90MB and it doesn't let go until I close the app.  The box is defined in the XAML.    The `Storyboard`, `DoubleAnimation`  and `PropertyPath`, etc, are all created ONCE, in the constructor.   The button code looks like this:

```
    private void button_Storyboard1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GC.Collect();

        if (_bFront)
        {
            _myDoubleAnimation.From = 0;
            _myDoubleAnimation.To = 180;
            _bFront = false;
        }
        else
        {
            _myDoubleAnimation.From = 180;
            _myDoubleAnimation.To = 0;
            _bFront = true;
        }
        _myDoubleAnimation.Duration = _Duration;
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(_myDoubleAnimation, "rotate_me");
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_myDoubleAnimation, _PropP);
        _sb.Children.Add(_myDoubleAnimation);
        _sb.Begin(this.viewport3D1);
    }
```

After a few rotations I'm out of memory!   What's going on?

Comment: please could you tell me what gfx card this is please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be totally wrong here, but aren't you adding _myDoubleAnimation to _sb.Children on each click, instead of just updating it?

Comment: I thought about that last night and tried doing
_sb.Children.Clear();   
before the Add()  with no effect.    I don't see a method called 'update' - what do you mean?  (pardon me, I'm a wpf newbie)

The gfx card is an ATi Radeon X300 which says it supports DirectX 9.0

Comment: ah-HAA!   But you were right anyway!    When I moved the Add to the C'Tor (so I only add it once)   changes to the Animation (To... and From...) are still recognized, but no more memory leaks!

Thank you!!!     


I still don't understand why _sb.Children.Clear() didn't help.

Comment: Nop, sounds weird :) I'd expect _sb.Children.Clear() to fix the leak as well :)